# how to send an email with wp_mail with an image on the email body

Tags: wp-mail

I can send emails using wp_mail, however any image on the body will not be display on the email received.
Is there any way of sending an image within the message

this is the code used to send emails:

```php
$to = 'someotheremail@mail.com';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: info@mywebsite.com');
$subject = "Olá $util, Benvindo(a) ao nosso site!";
$body = '
          <h3>Olá </h3></br>
          <p>Obrigado por se registar no site</p>
          <p>Saudações,</p>
          <p>my website</p>';
wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

this code works and send the email, however if I put an image tag with the src of my image, the image will not be displayed, had also try to send the image tag inside the body tag and still the same result.

Anyone!

Comment: did you modify the code for the question? The code in the question has a PHP syntax error on the first line

Comment: yes I did, only the email names. had already correct that on the $to variable.

Comment: can you modify it to show what you tried when you used img tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those with the same issue, here is my inteire code working, I had to put the img tag inside the subject body tag, also once I was using $_POST the link just didnt work, had made a work around using a word "[imagem]" to replace with img tag and the link uploaded.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="email_maker">
    <h2>Enviar vários emails</h2>
    <form action="?page=editor_redes" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="emails_assunto">Assunto:</label>
        <input type="text" name="emails_assunto" required><br>
        <label for="emails_msg">corpo de email:</label>
        <textarea name="emails_msg" rows="20" cols="80" required></textarea><br>
        <label for="emails_image">Banner publicitário: use no texto acima [imagem] e aqui apenas links de imagens online</label>
        <input type="text" name="emails_image"/><br>
        <div class="emails_conf">
          <input type="file" name="emails_file" required/>
          <label for="emails_file">Destinatários:</label>
        </div><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="emails_submit" value="enviar" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="email_preview">

  </div>
</div>
<style media="screen">
  .container{display:flex;}
  .email_maker{width:50%;}
  .email_maker h2{color:orange;margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:30px;}
  .email_maker form{display:grid;}
  .email_maker label[for=emails_file]{float:right;padding-right:10px;padding-top: 7px;}
  .email_maker input[type=file]{float:right; color:gray;}
  .email_maker input[type=submit]{background:lightyellow;border-radius: 7px;}
</style>
```

```php
if(isset($_FILES['emails_file'])){
  $path_to_wp = $_FILES['emails_file']['tmp_name'];
  $file = fopen($path_to_wp,"r");
  if (strpos($_POST['emails_msg'], '[imagem]')) {
    $ms = explode('[imagem]',$_POST['emails_msg']);
    $msg = $ms[0];
    $msg .= "<a href='https://ittca.github.io'><img src='".$_POST['emails_image']."'></a>";
    $msg .= $ms[1];
  } else {
    $msg = $_POST['emails_msg'];
  }
  $body = "<html><head></head><body>";
  $body .= $msg;
  $body .= "</body></html>";
  $a = 1;
  while(!feof($file)){
    $to = fgets($file);
    if($to != ""){
      $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: info@somemail.com');
      $enviado = wp_mail($to, $_POST['emails_assunto'], $body, $headers);
      if($enviado){
        echo '<p>'.$a.' [<a style="color:green;">OK</a>] '.$to.'</p>';
        $a+=1;
      } else {
        echo '<p>'.$a.' [<a style="color:red;"> erro </a>] '.$to.'</p>';
        $a+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  fclose($file);
}
```

and to make the wordpress wp_mail() work correctly I have this on my functions.php.

```php
if (! function_exists('email_sender')){
    add_action('phpmailer_init','email_sender');
    function email_sender($mail){
        $mail->SetFrom('whatever@hotmail.it', 'Tiago');
        $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'STARTTLS';
        $mail->Username = 'whatever@hotmail.it';
        $mail->Password = '1234567';
        $mail->IsSMTP();
    }
}
```